# Cannot update scatter chart NumberAxis metadata in JavaFX with FXML

Tags: javafx, charts, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to follow this guide:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/scatter-chart.htm
Guide's examples works fine but when trying to combine this with scene builder and FXML, I get some strange errors. First of all defaulted X axis as category axis and had to manually change it in the XML. Now the snippet looks like this:

```xml
<ScatterChart fx:id="modScatChart" layoutX="303.0" layoutY="122.0" title="Modify timeline" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
<xAxis>
  <NumberAxis fx:id="scatXAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
</xAxis>
<yAxis>
  <NumberAxis fx:id="scatYAxis" side="LEFT" />
</yAxis>
</ScatterChart>
```

The X axis need to be NumberAxis because the X values will be floating point date values normalized like 180th day of 2018 is appr. 2018,5. Now when trying to give the min, max, tick values to NumberAxis it seems that everything is ignored. It looks always like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqNNV.jpg)
Here is the relevant code snippet (GraphBean basically provides HashMap (milliseconds/loc where ms will be converted to date), minimum value for x axis and maximum value for y axis.

```java
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {   
        @FXML NumberAxis scatXAxis = new NumberAxis();
        @FXML NumberAxis scatYAxis = new NumberAxis();
        @FXML ScatterChart modScatChart = new ScatterChart(scatXAxis,scatYAxis);
    
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            try {
                setupGraphs();
            } catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }        
        }    
        private void setupGraphs() throws SQLException {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(new Date(graphsBean.getMinModMs())); 
                int minYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cal.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())); 
                int thisYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            
            scatXAxis = new NumberAxis(minYear, thisYear, 1);
            scatYAxis = new NumberAxis(0, graphsBean.getMaxLoc(), Math.round(graphsBean.getMaxLoc()/10));        
            
            scatXAxis.setLabel("Time");                
            scatYAxis.setLabel("Application size in loc");
            
            Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
            series1.setName("All");
            HashMap<Long, Integer> scatMap = graphsBean.getScatMap();
            for (Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entry : scatMap.entrySet()) {
                cal.setTime(new Date(entry.getKey())); 
                int curYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                float yearDayFlt = curYear+(float)(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))/365;
                series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(yearDayFlt, entry.getValue()));
            }
            modScatChart.getData().addAll(series1);
        }

}
```

Have also tried to fully initialize the NumberAxis with manual data at the start of the class, but still the same result. What the heck I'm missing here?

Comment: If you are using `FXML` you can not do `@FXML NumberAxis scatXAxis = new NumberAxis();`. All you need to do is `@FXML NumberAxis scatXAxis;`. Once you do `= new NumberAxis();`, you have overwritten your node in `FXML` and replace with with this new NumberAxis

Comment: Heh, that did the trick. Many thanks! Just present the objects and not initialize them. Still learning this FXML thing. So if understand correctly FXML does the initializing by itself with default values (if not presented somehow in XML)? And then you can later on change them like I used now: `scatXAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);` which automatically started the X axis numbering from minimum given value.